# Bash script that runs during terminal startup not working

Tags: python, macos, bash, unix, terminal

This is a snippet of code inside by .profile which is run during startup. I am not too sure why it is not source activate py33dev (which switches from default python 2.7 to 3.3) and cd to desktop does not work, even though the first cd and echo works.

> ```
> cd /Users/anaconda/envs/py33dev/bin
> echo 'source activate'
> source activate py33dev
> cd ~/Desktop/
> .....other bash script commands that work....
> ```

Comment: Are you sure you are using a user bash profile (eg not the generic - the ~ folder does not stand for that)

Comment: Yes, the other commands in the same .profile executes.